# Updates on PIVOTs in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

Is there a way to perform updates on a PIVOTed table in SQL Server 2008 where the changes propagate back to the source table, assuming there is no aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only really work if the pivoted columns form a unique identifier. So let's take Buggy's example; here is the original table:

```
TaskID    Date    Hours
```

and we want to pivot it into a table that looks like this:

```
TaskID    11/15/1980    11/16/1980    11/17/1980 ... etc.
```

In order to create the pivot, you would do something like this:

```
DECLARE @FieldList NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @FieldList =
    CASE WHEN @FieldList <> '' THEN 
        @FieldList + ', [' + [Date] + ']' 
    ELSE 
        '[' + [Date] + ']' 
    END
FROM
    Tasks



DECLARE @PivotSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotSQL = 
    '
        SELECT 
            TaskID
            , ' + @FieldList + '
        INTO
            ##Pivoted
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT * FROM Tasks
            ) AS T
        PIVOT
            (
                MAX(Hours) FOR T.[Date] IN (' + @FieldList + ') 
            ) AS PVT
    '

EXEC(@PivotSQL)
```

So then you have your pivoted table in `##Pivoted`. Now you perform an update to one of the hours fields:

```
UPDATE
    ##Pivoted
SET
    [11/16/1980 00:00:00] = 10
WHERE
    TaskID = 1234
```

Now `##Pivoted` has an updated version of the hours for a task that took place on 11/16/1980 and we want to save that back to the original table, so we use an `UNPIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @UnPivotSQL NVarChar(MAX)
SET @UnPivotSQL = 
    '
        SELECT
              TaskID
            , [Date]
            , [Hours]
        INTO 
            ##UnPivoted
        FROM
            ##Pivoted
        UNPIVOT
        (
            Value FOR [Date] IN (' + @FieldList + ')
        ) AS UP

    '

EXEC(@UnPivotSQL)

UPDATE
    Tasks
SET
    [Hours] = UP.[Hours]
FROM
    Tasks T
INNER JOIN
    ##UnPivoted UP
ON
    T.TaskID = UP.TaskID
```

You'll notice that I modified Buggy's example to remove aggregation by day-of-week. That's because there's no going back and updating if you perform any sort of aggregation. If I update the SUNHours field, how do I know which Sunday's hours I'm updating? This will only work if there is no aggregation. I hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome @brian. Thanks so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`PIVOT`s always require an aggregate function in the pivot clause.

Thus there is always aggregation.

So, no, it cannot be updatable.

**You CAN put an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` on a view based on the statement and thus you can make any view updatable.**

Example [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=120679)

Comment: How could I use the INSTEAD OF trigger to update the original table?

Answer (score 0):

this is just a guess, but can you make the query into a view and then update it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ElVieejo, thanks for your cut-n-paste comment.  However, I disagree with you analysis of my answer.

Comment: @ElVieejo, OP doesn't provide any details about their tables.  Under certain circumstances, you can issue an UPDATE on a view (it depends on details not provided).  If I had enough table info, and it was doable, I'd provide a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it is possible, but if you post specifics about the actual problem that you're trying to solve someone might be able to give you some advice on a different approach to handling it.