# Dynamically Bind gridview DataField

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table

```
table1

productName         category     S_Id    value

p1                 cat1           1        year
p1                 cat1           2        test1
p1                 cat1           3        test2


table2

S_Id                  specificatio

1                         year
2                         test1
3                         test2
```

and my need is to bind the grid view like

```
productName        category    year      test1    test2

p1                    cat1      1          2        3
```

I tried

```
select P.productName,P.category,S.specification from table1 P inner join table2 S on(P.S_Id=S.S_Id)
```

but it showing the result Like

```
 productName        category        specification

    p1                    cat1       year
    p1                    cat1       test1
    p1                    cat1       test2
```

can anyone help how to achieve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pivot you data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT     P.productName,
           P.category,
           S.specification,P.S_Id
FROM       #table1 P
INNER JOIN #table2 S ON( P.S_Id = S.S_Id ) )A
PIVOT (MAX(A.S_Id) FOR A.SPECIFICATION IN ([year],[test1],[test2])) PV
```

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726582/updates-on-pivots-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
create table table1
(
productname varchar(10),
category varchar(10),
S_Id int,
value varchar(10)
);

insert into table1 values('p1','cat1',1,'year');
insert into table1 values('p1','cat1',2,'test1');
insert into table1 values('p1','cat1',3,'test2');

create table table2
(
S_Id int,
specification varchar(10)
);

insert into table2 values(1,'year');
insert into table2 values(2,'test1');
insert into table2 values(3,'test2');
```

/*Dynamic Query for the expected result*/

```
Declare @cols varchar(max);
Declare @sql varchar(max);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(specification)
                from table2
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'');

 SET @SQL = N'select productName,category,'+@cols+'
    from
    (
    select t1.productname,t1.category,t2.S_ID,t2.Specification
    from table1 t1
    inner join 
    table2 t2
    on t1.S_ID = t2.S_ID
    )x
    pivot
    (
        MAX(S_Id) 
        FOR SPECIFICATION IN ('+@cols+')
    ) PV';
EXEC(@SQL);
```

**Result**:

```
productName   category  year  test1  test2
------------------------------------------
p1              cat1     1      2      3
```